# Comparison the words with the original file in the R

Tags: json, r

I have original dataset in json format. Let's load it in R.

```
library("rjson")
setwd("mydir")
getwd()
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("N1.json"), collapse=""))
uu <- unlist(json_data)
uutext <- uu[names(uu) == "text"]
```

And I have another dataset mydata2

```
mydata=read.csv(path to data/words)
```

I need to find the words in mydata2, only which are present in messages in json file. And then write this messages into  the new document, "xyz.txt" How to do it?

```
    chalk      indirect          pick    reaction            team      skip    pumpkin     surprise         bless  ignorance
1     time       patient          road      extent          decade  cemetery  staircase      monarch        bubble      abbey
2  service  conglomerate        banish         pan        friendly  position      tight    highlight          rice  disappear
3    write         swear         break        tire             jam   neutral   momentum  requirement  relationship     matrix
4  inspire          dose          jump     promote           trace    latest   absolute       adjust      joystick      habit
5    wrong        behave         claim    dedicate          threat      sell   particle    statement         teach       lamb
6      eye        tissue  prescription     problem       secretion   revenge     barrel        beard     mechanism   platform
7   forest          kick          face   wisecrack     uncertainty     ratio   complain        doubt    reflection    realism
8    total           fee        debate        hall            soft     smart        sip       ritual          pill   category
9  contain      headline          lump  absorption  superintendent   digital   increase          key        banner     second

 i mean
 chalk -1 number1     indirect -2 number2
```

template

```
Word1-1 number1-1; Word1-2 number 1-2; …; Word 1-10 number 1-10
Word2-1 number2-1; Word2-2 number 2-2; …; Word 2-10 number 2-10
```

Comment: We are very unlikely to go and download something just to answer you. Pls post a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Next time pls include real data. Simplified model:

```
library(data.table) 
word = c("test","meh","blah")
jsonF = c("let's do test", "blah is right", "test blah", "test test") 

outp <- list()
for (i in 1:length(word)) {
 outp[[i]] = as.data.frame(grep(word[i],jsonF,v=T,fixed=T)) # possibly, ignore.case=T
}

qq = rbindlist(outp)
qq = unique(qq)
print(qq)

1:               let's do test
2:                   test blah
3:                   test test
4:               blah is right
```

Edit: quick and dirty paste/collapse:

```
library(data.table)

x = LETTERS[1:10]
y = LETTERS[11:20]

df = rbind(x,y)    

L = list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  L[i] = paste0(df[i,],"-",seq(1,10)," ",i,"-",seq(1,10),collapse="; ")

}
Fin = cbind(L)
View(Fin)
```

Gives:

```
> Fin
L                                                                                           
    [1,] "A-1 1-1; B-2 1-2; C-3 1-3; D-4 1-4; E-5 1-5; F-6 1-6; G-7 1-7; H-8 1-8; I-9 1-9; J-10 1-10"
    [2,] "K-1 2-1; L-2 2-2; M-3 2-3; N-4 2-4; O-5 2-5; P-6 2-6; Q-7 2-7; R-8 2-8; S-9 2-9; T-10 2-10"
```

Comment: Thank you , Alexey!  Could you tell me.  In mydata2 https://www.mediafire.com/?fw6x4c0mv7r5gar How to write in the new dataset the first 10 words in this format.                                                          Word1-1 number1-1; Word1-2 number 1-2; …; Word 1-10 number 1-10
Word2-1 number2-1; Word2-2 number 2-2; …; Word 2-10 number 2-10, i need to arrange it for further analysis.
Thanks

Comment: @fenton. Could you, pls, `dput` first 10 words from that file as well as first 10-15 rows from JSON file? For safety reasons not everyone will go and download unknown files from unknown sources

Comment: What do you mean by "Word1-1 number1-1"? Just list all words in one column and run a `seq(1,N)` to make an identifier for each word

Comment: Alexey, now i have edited my post with example)) Do you understand

Comment: I did understand that, but what's the purpose? You are not going to compare a string of words + numbers to JSON, are you? From original post you want to check if word[i] is in one of JSON strings and write that JSON string to text file.

Comment: Indeed, i need it to arrange them  for another analysis in other soft/ Can you help me?

Comment: that problem, i decided. But i got new problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159784/count-the-word-in-corpus-in-r
maybe you can help me, please!