# Arrange the words of the Document Term Matrix by frequency in R

Tags: r, tm

i'm sorry for new question , but i newbie in text mining, and need in advices of profy.
Now, after long torments with `content_transformer` i have clean corpus
The next question

```
1. How  select from `dtm`  the words with small frequencies , so that the amount of frequencies was not more than 1%
```

For example i need this format

```
x 0,5% of all words in the dataset
y 0,2%
z 0,3%
```

so here total frequencies sum =1%
How do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into the `termDocumentMatrix` function of the `tm` package. This contains a way to count the occurrences of the words per document. Adding these numbers over the total corpus should lead you where you want to be.

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
# wordcounts for complete corpus
counts <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))

# number of documents
nb <- length(counts)
# frequencies
freqs <- counts / nb
```

Comment: could you show the code please and and how select the words with small frequencies , so that the amount of frequencies was not more than 1%
Thank you

Comment: Thank you, it's good. But how to find the words  total frequency sum of which equal=1% and write it in new dataset, can you show me the code?